# How to turn on the 'throwIfNamespace' flag in React.js

Tags: reactjs, svg, xml-namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I have some code like below in my component.

```html
<svg id="SvgjsSvg3254" width="318" height="152" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" class="apexcharts-svg" xmlns:data="ApexChartsNS" transform="translate(0, 0)" style="background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
```

I am getting error like below

> Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can turn on the 'throwIfNamespace' flag to bypass this warning.

How can I turn on the `throwIfNamespace` flag ?

[image]

Comment: i used
for an attribute like **xmlns:xlink** try using **xmlnsXlink**  while exporting svg as react component.

Answer (score 55):

You are getting the error because of this `xmlns:xlink` syntax, React does not know how to compile this. Use camel case notation, i.e. `xmlnsXlink`.

Try this:

```html
<svg id="SvgjsSvg3254" width="318" height="152" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlnsSvgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" class="apexcharts-svg" xmlnsData="ApexChartsNS" transform="translate(0, 0)" style="background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Appreciated such a simple solution! I had to replace `xlink:href` to `xlinkHref` as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and also is not helpful if using provided SVG that you do not control.

Comment: Is there a tool for converting svg that is not camel case into camel case?

Comment: Didn't work for me on Next.js 13.

Comment: For React, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

`throwIfNamespace` is an option of `@babel/preset-react`, or more specifically, `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`. See [this page on the babeljs site](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) for an example configuration file that sets `throwIfNamespace` to false as well as more information regarding the option.

An example here for convenience with the following file:

**index.js**

```html
<element ns:attr />
```

**.babelrc with default throwIfNamespace (true)**

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"
    ]
  ]
}
```

yields similar to what you see:

```
$ npx babel index.js 
SyntaxError: /tmp/throw-if-namespace/index.js: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can set `throwIfNamespace: false` to bypass this warning.
> 1 | <element ns:attr />
```

**.babelrc with throwIfNamespace set to false**

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
        "throwIfNamespace": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

yields no error

```
$ npx babel index.js 
/*#__PURE__*/
React.createElement("element", {
  "ns:attr": true
});
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but this is literally not working for me. Not sure if this is the case for anyone else.

Comment: Two things seem to have changed since this answer was originally written: 1) the babel installed by npx by default is now out-of-date. See @babel/cli docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-cli/ 2) it seems that @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx no longer works out-of-the-box and you have to spin up a project and npm install it, otherwise you'll get missing module errors. So, for this to work as written, create an empty directory and  `npm install @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` beforehand. After making this adjustment, the example still works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this issue.
In my case, I had to remove all the unnecessary namespace in the SVG image and it started working as a react component.

[image]

You can see the difference between the two SVG contents.
**Correct one is the one at the bottom in the image.**

OR you can upload and parse your data through this link : [here](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

Ref: [Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7955)

Comment: That's not really a fix. You just removed the XML attributes causing the bug... you still need them.

Comment: not a valid solution as this doesnot help ,,, all svgs cannot be simplified this way

Comment: Another solution is to use camelCase 
ex:
<svg xlinkHref="http://i.imgur.com/w7GCRPb.png" />

Ref:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4908

Answer (score 1):

Use the attributes properly:

- instead of `class` write `className`
- in `style` use camel notation
- and add the style in the brackets

  ```
  className={`name`}
      style={{
                  stroke: "none",
                  strokeWidth: 4,
                  strokeDasharray: "none",
                  strokeLinecap: "butt",
                  strokeLinejoin: "miter",
                  strokeMiterlimit: 10,
                  fill: "#99CC33",
                  fillRule: "nonzero",
                  opacity: 1,
                }}
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Used some animation from CodePen and had the same problem. Like suggested before, i turned the xml parts into camelCase and had to put style in curly brackets.

Image of not working and fixed code:
[image]

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that. I had the same Error when i used and svg from CodePen. I didn't answer the question, but i gave a solution on how to get rid of the error.